# Who is this minifigure: black trousers, blue shirt with id and rescue item, sunglasses

Tags: minifigure-identification

[image]

Who is this minifigure: black trousers, blue shirt with id and rescue item, sunglasses?
What set can it be from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [this guy](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=res008#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) but without the hat.

Comment: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=67.626.610

Comment: I found it, it´s indeed a coast guard.